# Retrive my database values from my database and then using them on a programmatic SMS message?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm confused and cannot figure out how I can send an SMS message using values stored on my database.

The SMS would appear like this: `('NAME'... Message content, etc..)`, the message would then be sent using the contact numbers entered by the user on the sqlite database.

Here's the code I've used to get the data during signup.

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter  {
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
        "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME text, PASSWORD text, NAME text, C1 integer, C2 integer); ";
// Variable to hold the database instance
public SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    db.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String userName,String password, String name, String cn1, String cn2) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
    newValues.put("NAME",name);
    newValues.put("C1", cn1);
    newValues.put("C2", cn2);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
    // Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public int deleteEntry(String UserName) {
    //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
    String where="USERNAME=?";
    int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
    // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
}

public String getSingleEntry(String userName) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) { // username doesn't exist
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

public boolean isExist (String userName) {
    boolean exists;
    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) { // username exists
        exists = true;
        cursor.close();
        return exists;
    }
    return false;
}

public void updateEntry(String userName,String password) {
    // Define the updated row content.
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

    String where="USERNAME = ?";
    db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}}
```

And here is the SignUpActivity

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bSignup;
TextView tvSign;
EditText etUN, etPW, etPW2, etFN, etC1, etC2;
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    bSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSignup);
    tvSign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSign);
    etUN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUN);
    etPW = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW);
    etPW2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW2);
    etFN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFN);
    etC1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etC1);
    etC2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etC2);

    bSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = etUN.getText().toString();
            String password = etPW.getText().toString();
            String password2 = etPW2.getText().toString();
            String name = etFN.getText().toString();
            String c1 = etC1.getText().toString();
            String c2 = etC2.getText().toString();

            // check if fields are vacant
            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("") || password2.equals("") || name.equals("")
                    || c1.equals("")|| c2.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incomplete Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // check if passwords 1 and 2 match
            if (!password.equals(password2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords don't match. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            //check is username is still available for use
            if (loginDataBaseAdapter.isExist(username)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username already taken. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            else {
            // allow data to be saved in the database
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(username, password, name, c1, c2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    tvSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Once I'm logged in, how can I get those values ("i.e. NAME, C1, and C2") and send an SMS by pushing a button?

*Update*

I've used this on my LoginDataBaseAdapter.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap <String,String> user = new HashMap <String,String> ();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "LOGIN";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        user.put("USERNAME", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("PASSWORD", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("NAME", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("C1", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("C2", cursor.getString(5));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}
```

Then this code at my HomeActivity:

```
 tvHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
    HashMap <String, String> details = loginDataBaseAdapter.getUserDetails();
    String name_text = details.get("NAME");
    tvHello.setText("Welcome " + name_text);
```

It seems that it can only get the first entry and not the current entry for the current user. Any ideas to fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it right. So I'll answer my own question.

Create a editText area wherein you'll enter your name to retrieve. Then use this code to retrieve it

```
public String getData(String verif) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{verif}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "No records exist";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String get_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
    cursor.close();
    return get_name;
}
```

Once retrieved, set the name in a TextView. Then convert it to string like so:

```
String myName = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

Then:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, "My name is "+ myName ,null,   
null);
```

'number' is a String containing the contact number where you want to send your SMS